# Where's the 'invalid flag' flag?

Tags: support, flagging, flags

I joked recently here that the "Flag or disagree" button is misleading in that there is in fact no "disagree" option presented.  This bugs me most, of course, when I go through the queue and see flags I disagree with -- there's the plain as day invitation, but the interface does not fulfil the promise.

Yet obviously there is a way to cast an "invalid flag" vote since those are noted on the right.  On the [U&L help page for the moderator tools privilege](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), there's a section about "Handling flags" which notes:

> you have a number of options [...including] *Flag as 'invalid flag'.*
>   Use this option if you feel the flag should be ignored or not acted
>   upon by moderators. This will be visible in the flag list.

I've had this privilege for a while but still can't find the option.  What's up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see an option to say other flags are invalid when I access the reviews under the new colored links that show up in our toolbars at the top.

[image: ss #1]

Comment: I absolutely *do not* see that, I just get the other 5 options, so perhaps it happens at 20k (later this week me thinks...).  If so, you probably never noticed because you went from 15 to 20 too darned fast cowboy ;)

Comment: @goldilocks seriously? What do you see? I had the same dialogue long before breaching the 20k wall.

Comment: @goldilocks - Ah shucks thanks 8-)

Comment: @terdon I'm gonna give up on computers and literacy and become a lumberjack.  Or something. I actually *took a screenshot* parallel to slm's and was in the midst of scrawling "Where??" on it when I realized it is there.  I'm still convinced it's not always there though (I also just noticed "very low quality" is also not always there, and I have that screenshot, lol).  I have gone over this a bunch of times.  Really.  Honestly.  My mind is obviously better at deception that I had hoped. :(

Comment: @goldilocks - VLQ is only on A's not Q's.

Comment: Oh I think there are some VLQ Q's too ;)  Sheesh. So much for claiming "an eye for detail".